# How to count torrent seeders and peers?

Tags: php, bittorrent

How can I create a seeder and peer counter for a torrent tracking site ?

Comment: Sure, otherwise there wouldn't be any, would there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Know the number of seeds/peers for a torrent in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865868/how-to-know-the-number-of-seeds-peers-for-a-torrent-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the php based [RivetTracker](http://www.rivetcode.com/software/rivettracker/) which has an implementation of this.