# can't get all the information from RSS feed

Tags: javascript, rss

I'm trying to make a chrome extension for The pirate bay. I'm using a RSS feed to get the feed for certian categorys. Such as movies. All I'm able to get is the author, the name of the torrent, and the date created. I want to be able to get the seeders,  the size of the torrent, and the magnet url, for direct download. I'm using this feed: http://rss.thepiratebay.se/201. Am I using the correct feed?

The code I have isn't much, but if you need it let me know.

Comment: As the first reply says, yes the RSS feed don't provide any information and you can't do much with JS. But if you are willing to take some challenge and might have a look into this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865868/how-to-know-the-number-of-seeds-peers-for-a-torrent-in-php

Answer (score 2):

seems their feed doesn't support for all attributes. it contains link and title only. here is one node contains.

```
  <item>
        <title><![CDATA[Choose Me 1984 DVDRip x264-HANDJOB]]></title>
        <link>magnet:?xt=urn:btih:4FAFD622253EE46F31172140407CA3D2B439B053&amp;dn=Choose+Me+1984+DVDRip+x264-HANDJOB</link>
        <comments>http://thepiratebay.se/torrent/10593993</comments>
        <pubDate>Sun, 20 Jul 2014 06:30:33 +0200</pubDate>
        <category domain="http://thepiratebay.se/browse/201"><![CDATA[Video / Movies]]></category>
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[hotpena]]></dc:creator>
        <guid>http://thepiratebay.se/torrent/10593993/</guid>
        <torrent xmlns="http://xmlns.ezrss.it/0.1/">
            <contentLength>1681299254</contentLength>
            <infoHash>4FAFD622253EE46F31172140407CA3D2B439B053</infoHash>
            <magnetURI><![CDATA[magnet:?xt=urn:btih:4FAFD622253EE46F31172140407CA3D2B439B053&amp;dn=Choose+Me+1984+DVDRip+x264-HANDJOB]]></magnetURI>
        </torrent>
    </item>
```